# My UV changes are not showing up in the viewport

Tags: uv

I am practicing with UV Unwrap, using a checker texture on a mesh. I do the smart unwrap and the UV's change in the UV editor, but the changes do not update in the viewport. I can grab a cluster of UV's and move it around but the change does appear on the object. I am sure this is a setting but I don't know what to change. Can you all help? Thanks!

Comment: maybe you have created a second UV map, delete the wrong one

Comment: Nope--I checked and there's only one UV map

Comment: I deleted the UV Map and unwrapped again, and nothing changed in the viewport. How is that even possible?

Comment: Check if under "View" is checked "Update Automatically" ... or share your blend via https://blend-exchange.com (copy-paste given code into your Question by Edit

Comment: Maybe pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/